# Need clarification regarding computed properties

Tags: swift

I am currently learning Swift from a Java/Node.js background. After reading about computed properties, I was wondering as to the difference between the following two uses:

```
private var _privateVariable: String = "test"

var testVariable {
   return _privateVariable
}

var testVariable {
   get{
      return _privateVariable
   }
}
```

Essentially, what is the difference in usage between using a getter with the `get` keyword and simply returning another variable within the original variable declaration?

Comment: This is covered under the "Read-only Computed Properties" section of the [Computed Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID259) section of the [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH3-ID0) book. *"You can simplify the declaration of a read-only computed property by removing the get keyword and its braces"*

Comment: You can just do this, btw: `public private(set) publicallyReadablePrivatelyMutableVariable = foo`

Comment: @Alexander But that's not a computed property.

Comment: @rmaddy I know, but often people use computed properties to expose a public getter to a private stored property, not knowing that stored properties can be public but with private setters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference at all. This is a mere shortcut.

When you write

```
var testVariable {
   get{
      return _privateVariable
   }
}
```

you can add setter at any point:

```
var testVariable {
   set{
      _privateVariable = newValue
   }
   get{
      return _privateVariable
   }
}
```

While the other case is useful to shorten your code when you don't need a setter.